# Should I always use dynamic script tag injection technique for including javascript files, similar to Facebook?

Tags: javascript

Instead of just including `<script src="...">` tag on a page as usual, facebook recommends loading its SDK library in the following way:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
```

Saying, that:

> The best place to put the asynchronous version of the code is right after the opening `<body>` tag. This allows Facebook initialization to happen in parallel with the initialization on the rest of your page.

If it is that great then maybe I should always use this method in all my projects for any external javascript include? When it is appropriate to use this technique and what are the reasons against it?

Comment: You might want to google for LabJS and/or RequireJS - not because you should necessarily use them, but because you might find some good information.

Answer (score 3):

Every script-tag forces the browser to stop loading, until the script-block is fully loaded and executed. By dynamically adding the script-tag, the page could be fully loaded without blocking. For further info have a look at [Loading Javascript without blocking](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/06/23/loading-javascript-without-blocking/) and/or [loading scripts without blocking](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/27/loading-scripts-without-blocking/)

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronously loading a script sounds good, but do you need to do it in an inline `<script>` tag?

What about loading it while handling the `onload` of the page?

```
function init() {
    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        e.async = true;
        document.body.appendChild(e);
    }());
}

window.addEventListener("load", init, false);
```

Perhaps Facebook's way ensures all script-enabled browsers process the script, but you can pretty much ensure those same browsers handle the script with a nice addEventListener/attachEvent abstraction function.